# format DataGridTextColumn from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, string.format, datagridtextcolumn

Maybe, I think, things are too simple.
I have a datagrid, dynamically adding columns from code behind. This works.
Then I have columns with integer-values, which I would like to see right-aligned in the column, but it fails. My Code is:

```
    public List<List<int>> IntegerData { get; set; }................

            DataGridTextColumn textC = new DataGridTextColumn();
            textC.Header = ("Column");
            textC.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));    
            textC.Binding.StringFormat = "00000";
```

and at the end I have something like:

```
            myDataGrid.Itemssource = IntegerData
```

With the textC.Binding.String.Format the problem is: (First: it seems, that the stringFormat-LIne correctly overloads the previous line)

Format "0" gives an integer "1" "2", which is correct.

Format "00000" gives "00001" "00002" "00003"  which is correct for String-Format, but not, what I would like to have

BUT:

Format "######"  gives also "1" "2" .. and so on (left-aligned, no leading blanks)

Due to formatting-rules I would have expected (or hoped), that ##### is placeholder as described and the result is "bbbb1"  , "bbbb2"   right-aligned. (b is here for blank!)

So Binding seems to deal correctly with the "00000" Format, but not with "######" Format.
Has anybody any idea or experience with that idea? (all other Bindings, I find in internet, are much more complicated)

Comment: thanks for editing my question. I am german, no native english speaker. nevertheless i enjoy improving not only sw-development, but also my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve your problem by creating a style rather than formating the text in the cell.

first, create a style:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right));
```

than assign the style to the column

```
textC.CellStyle = style;
```